# removing import/no-cycle warnings from project

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Working on removing this warning from a github project.
Need help understanding how to separate out the logic correctly.
My question is for this component they combined the logic for checkboxes, switches, and inputs. Does it make sense to split this logic into an input / switch / checkbox component?

The component in question is an input. The dependencies occurs because the main index page calls in the **InputSwitch** component to determine wether to show an input or a switch element and within the logic for InputSwitch the toggle between showing an input and a switch requires an import of the **index.jsx**.

on the **InputSwitch** component I've tried to call the **InputDefault** component as a replacement for the **Input** since I assumed it was the root component for the input settings one but it ends up failing a few tests related to props.

**index.jsx**

```
displaySwitch = () => {
    const {
      type,
      id,
      name,
      label,
      value,
      checked,
      uncheckedValue,
    } = this.props;
    if (type === 'switch' && label && name) {
      return (
        <InputSwitch
          id={id}
          name={name}
          label={label}
          value={value}
          checked={checked}
          uncheckedValue={uncheckedValue}
        />
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

displayContent = () => {
    const {
      dark, small, accordion, large, type,
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={`${dark ? css.dark : ''} ${large ? css.large : ''} ${
          small ? css.small : ''
        } ${type === 'hidden' ? css.hidden : ''}`}
      >
        {!accordion && (
          <div className={css.labelNoAccordion}>{this.displayLabel()}</div>
        )}
        {this.displayDefault()}
        {this.displayCheckbox()}
        {this.displayCheckboxGroup()}
        {this.displaySelect()}
        {this.displayTextarea()}
        {this.displayTag()}
        {this.displaySwitch()}
        {this.displayLocation()}
        {this.displaySubmit()}
        {this.displayError()}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

**InputSwitch**

```
displaySwitchHidden = () => {
    const {
      id, name, label, value, uncheckedValue,
    } = this.props;
    const { checked, key } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className={css.switchHidden}>
        <Input
          id={id}
          key={key}
          type="checkbox"
          name={name}
          label={label}
          value={value}
          uncheckedValue={uncheckedValue}
          checked={checked}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

It seems like there is a lot of functionality stuffed into this component and it seems like it makes sense to get this separated out.

link to the relevant parts of this project:
https://github.com/ifmeorg/ifme/tree/master/client/app/components/Input

Thank you for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this with how I was able to resolve this.

I noticed that the input under InputSwitch
was just a checkbox.
I imported in the component **InputCheckbox** instead and ran all the tests which passed.